# what does 'build a gcc cross compiler' mean?

Tags: gcc, cross-platform

I am very new to linux and GCC. The price of raspberry pi lured me in. I am interested in using GCC to cross compile some C Code to target some embedded hardware, specifically a Cortex-M3 micro. I eventually want to have a full suite of compiler/programmer/debugger, but for now I'm starting with compiler.

So I did a quick non-cross compile test on the RP3, and all was well. Now I am researching how to cross compile and target my uc. The gcc documentation online seems to indicate that I can use the plain vanilla gcc, and just specify some command line options to perform cross compilation: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html

But searching around, I find a lot of people mentioning building a gcc cross compiler. What does this mean?

Does gcc have options to double as a cross compiler? If so, why would one desire "building" a cross compiler?

Comment: See *Cross-Compiler-Specific Options* about 90% of the way through the [GCC install instructions](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html#TOC3) (GCC 6.2.0 version — the URL might change in future, though the base portion is version neutral)..

Comment: So the GCC that was included in the RP3 can't behave like a cross compiler? I will have to follow that link and rebuild GCC from source, providing the correct cross-compiler options? The output of those process will be a cross compiler specific to the Cortex-M3? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Since I know nothing about either the RP3 or Cortex-M3, I can't say whether the cross-compiler for one can cross-compile to the other, but there's a fair chance that the answer is 'no'.  And if that's the case, you'll either have to find a cross-compiler that someone else has built for you or build it yourself.  That probably won't be easy — but I've never tried building a GCC cross-compiler so I'm not sure of that.  Beware the other infrastructure you may need — the `binutils` for the cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

A cross-compiler is one that is created on machine type A (combination of hardware and o/s) and either runs on a different machine type B or runs on type A but produces software to be run on a different machine type B.

Thus, if you have a Linux machine using an x86_64 CPU and running on some version of Linux, but you compile GCC so that it will run on an IBM PowerPC platform running some version of AIX, you would be creating a cross-compiler.

Another variant might be having a compiler on Linux using an x86_64 CPU that runs on the Linux machine but produces code for an embedded hardware chip.  You'd then benefit from the CPU power of the Linux machine while deploying to a much smaller, less powerful system that maybe has no o/s of its own, or only a minimal o/s.